# TSQL: combination of two table

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables

A

```
EmpID IDcard  Date
xxx   111     2018-10-01
zzz   111     2018-05-01
```

B

```
Idcard AgrNumb Date
111    x46     2018-10-01
111    x35     2018-05-01
111    x20     2017-12-01
111    x42     2018-08-01
```

I would like to make table in which I will have one row from the first table and one from the second table. Row from the second table should be the first row which is smaller from the date in first row. It should looks this way:

IDcard Date

```
111 2018-10-01 --> table A
111 2018-08-01 --> table B
111 2018-05-01 --> table A
111 2017-12-01 --> table B
```

I don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: it is unclear that exactly is your expected outcome. I could not derive it from the result. What are the criteria, how the rows are selected (e.g. why is the 4th rsult line the 3rd row from table B?)? and why do you want to interleave the tables? this is rather unusual and let me guess, that your data base design is awkward and should be reworked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try(if in sql-server):

```
        Select T2.*, EmpID  from Table1 T1
        outer apply(
         select t2_in.idCard, min(date) as DateT2
         from table2 t2_in 
         where t2_in.idCard = t1.IDcard
         group by t2_in.idCard
        )t2
```

Comment: It doesnt work well. Now I get min(date) from B but I need smaller date than that in A but the biggest from the table B. And I need to this for each row seperate.